# Получить начальное значение Ajax

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как получить начальное значение ($14) с этого  [САЙТА](http://alex.devel.softservice.org/testapi/) с помощью AJAX

Comment: Вот скрипт
https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/q50w2sL4/14/

Comment: Функцией JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

Для начала не делай запрос по `http://` протоколу он устарел, браузер будет ругаться и может заблокировать запрос в целях безопасности. Видим в консоли:

> *loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://alex.devel.softservice.org/testapi/'. **This request has been
>   blocked;  the content must be served over HTTPS.***

Делай запрос по протоколу `https://`, я проверил, так тоже будет работать.

#### fetch API

```
fetch('https://alex.devel.softservice.org/testapi/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.balance_usd);
});
```

#### jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://alex.devel.softservice.org/testapi/'
}).done(data => {
  console.log(data.balance_usd);
});
```

Comment: подскажите как вернуть значение с ajax в переменную? чтобы подставить эту переменную в значение по умолчанию https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8q1a/RRupUNW6v

Comment: Просто так поместить значение в переменую не получится, ajax это асинхронная операция, а js выполняется синхронно. Подождите пока запрос завершится и перерисуйте что надо в блоке `.done()` Вот форк вашего демо https://jsfiddle.net/zrkmbjt0/ Почитайте про асинхронные операции в JS это большая тема которую нужно понимать.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Подскажите еще пожалуйста момент http://joxi.ru/LmGgqZ6feKRRZm

Comment: Так это событие, ставити обработчик и меняете значение в слайдере

Comment: Поменял немного CSS и HTML вынес знак доллора из инпута, теперь `input type=number` https://jsfiddle.net/zrkmbjt0/32/ в общем все сделал за вас ))

Comment: почему то значение все равно не перемещается за курсором.. http://joxi.ru/RmzBK8PH0QMd5m

Comment: Ну тут совсем другая задача, делаете div шириной как у поля для курсора с position: relative, внутри него другой div, где будет значение вывода, с позицией position:absolute, и вычисляете в процентах отступ слева в момент slide на slidere.

Comment: добавил в divы и добавил к ним position, но не понимаю каким образом мне теперь сделать чтобы было передвижение за курсором..    "вычисляете в процентах отступ слева в момент slide на slidere это надо в JS что то прописывать? https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/zrkmbjt0/40/